# Monaca Editor syntax highlighting is ok, but editor doesn't show any errors

Tags: editor, monaco-editor

Syntax highlighting is ok, but doesn't show any errors.
Line 5 should show an error in red at end of the line in editor, but not.
Why could that be?

[image: Monaco editor doesn't show any error]

I'm using monaco webpack plugin, with these config.

**index.js**

```
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api';
import 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/basic-languages/javascript/javascript';
import 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/basic-languages/python/python';

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('duzenleyici'), {
    value: ``,
    language: 'python',
    theme: 'vs-dark',
    wordWrap: true,
    automaticLayout: true,
});
```

**webpack-config.js**

```
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'monaco.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.ttf$/,
                use: ['file-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
            languages: ['javascript', 'python'],
            features: ['find', 'bracketMatching', 'comment', 'folding', 'suggest', 'contextmenu', 'coreCommands', 'codeAction', 'clipboard', 'linesOperations', 'suggest', 'wordHighlighter'],
            globalAPI: true,
            // publicPath: '/',
        }),
    ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In *index.js* :

`
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api';

```
        // validation settings
        monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
            noSemanticValidation: false,
        });

        // compiler options
        monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
            target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES6,
            allowNonTsExtensions: true
        });
```

`

In *webpack-config.js* **plugins** key:

```
new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
        languages: ['javascript', 'typescript']
    })
```